# How there can be more than one shortest path between two vertices in a network?

Tags: networking, graph-theory

I was reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) about distance in  networks, the writer says:

> Notice that there may be more than one shortest path between two vertices.

I could not get the idea “more than one shortest path between two vertices . 
Shortest path should not be the shortest path? 
Can someone clarify this to me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. Here's a proof by construction in a bidirectional graph with unweighted (or equally-weighted) edges:

```
             a --- e
           /   \   |
           b   c   f
           \   /   |
             d --- h
```

Between vertices `a` and `d`, there are three paths: `a->b->d`, `a->c->d` and `a->e->f->h->d`. Both `a->b->d` and `a->c->d` have length 3 and are both equally the shortest path, proving the hypothesis.

Comment: Supposing that  edges weights of a->c-d and a->b-> are all them same , correct?